# Use a variable and assign an expression to it in one step in Raku

Tags: raku

I'm trying to use a variable and assign an expression to it in one step:

The given (sample) code

```
my @l=<a b c d e f g h i j k>;
my $i=0;
while $i < 7 {
    say @l[$i];
    $i= ($i+1) * 2;
}

# Output:
# a
# c
# g
```

The desired functionality:

```
my @l=<a b c d e f g h i j k>;
my $i=0;
say @l[$i =~ ($i+1) * 2] while $i < 7;
# Here, first the @l[$i] must be evaluated 
# then $i must be assigned to the expression
# ($i+1) * 2 
# (The =~ operator is selected just as an example)

# Output:
# The same output as above should come, that is:
# a
# c
# g
```

After the variable `$i` is used, the (sample) expression `($i+1) * 2` should be assigned to it in one step and that should take place *solely inside the array index* `@l[$i =~ ($i+1) * 2]`  i.e. the argument of `while` should *not* be changed.

Here I took the Regex equation operator `=~` (check and assign operator, AFAIK) just as an example. In this context of course, it did not work. 
I need to Are there any operators or some workaround to achieve that functionality?  Thank you.

Comment: The question is really vague: 1. you don't specify the required output. 2. You seem to be mixing integers (`$i`) with string operations (`lt`). 3. you seem to misunderstand what the postfix `++` does (`$i =~ $i++`).  Could you at least provide the required output?  Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I've edited the original post to address the issues you've pointed out.  Yes, `lt` is not suitable fro integers (I've noticed it after taking a look at the Perl 6 docs) As for the `=~` operator, it's there jsut as an example operator. I've chosen it because it does the closest thing I want to achieve: It checks a Regex and then assigns a alue to it in one step. For instance in `say $same if ($same =~ m/^$re$/g)` (Perl 5) `$same` is both checked and if check returns True, it's assiged a value.

Comment: @LarsMalmsteen I remain confused. I would not expect `$same` to be assigned a value in any circumstances via the code `say $same if ($same =~ m/^$re$/g)`. And sure enough, running [that code in tio](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z@3UkGlODE3VcFWQd3ESN2aCyRQlKqgABLQ0wMKFBRl5pVAFWWmKWhAldcp5OrHAVWq6KdrWisoK5gY/f8PAA) leaves it unchanged despite the check being true. Please consider explaining specific circumstances in which `$same` *can ever* be assigned a value with the line of code you've quoted. TIA.

Comment: @raiph You're correct, that piece of code doesn't assign a value to `$same` I have put it in a hurry to depict the kind of functionality I was trying to explain. There I was actually trying to tell the so-called 'Capture Group' method in which the substrings fulfilling the regex being assigned to variables `$1` , `$2` (using that same operator `=~`) but I erroneously talked about the `$same` instead of those `$1` variable. When you think about this Capture Groups method, it sort of depicts the 'use & assign' mechanism (albeit very roughly)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean, something like this?

```
my @l = <a b c d e f g h i j k>; 
say @l[ 0, (* + 1) * 2 ...^ * > 7 ]; # says a c g;
```

A little bit more verbose:

```
my @l = <a b c d e f g h i j k>; 
say @l[ 0, -> $i { ($i + 1) * 2 } ...^ -> $i { $i > 7 } ];
```

Or even

```
my sub next-i( $i ) { ($i + 1) * 2 };
my sub last-i( $i ) { $i > 7 };

my @l = <a b c d e f g h i j k>; 
say @l[ 0, &next-i ...^ &last-i ];
```

Edit: Or, if as in the comment below you know the number of elements beforehand, you can get rid of the end block and (simplify?) to

```
say @l[ (0, (* + 1) * 2 ... *)[^3] ];
```

Edit:

*using a variable and assigning an expression to it in one step*

Well, the result of an assignment is the assigned value, if that is what you mean/want, so if you insist on using a `while` loop, this might work for you.

```
my @l = <a b c d e f g h i j k>; 
my $i = -1; say @l[ $i = ($i + 1) * 2 ] while $i < 3;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. While it presents good use of sequences, it doesn't solve the basic problem, which is using a variable and assigning an expression to it in one step.

Comment: The 'edit' answers the question because when I tried it, it worked. Now it looks *using a variable and assigning an expression to it in one step* is quite simple and intuitive in Raku. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
my @l=<a b c d e f g h i j k>;
my $i=0;
say @l[($=$i,$i=($i+1)*2)[0]] while $i < 7'

a
c
g
```

A bit of cheating using `$`.  Otherwise, it didn't work...

I would have thought `($i,$i=($i+1)*2)[0]` would have done the trick.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you explain the structure of the part inside the array index of `@l` i.e. what does the `$` represent and usage of komma inside the array index.

Comment: The index of `@l` is `(x,y)[0]` which is just a two element array that is immediately indexed to return the 0th element i.e. `x`. The `$` is something that I'm still trying to wrap my head around.  It's like each expression or statement has a single unnamed `$` variable available that's scoped to that statement.  I could have defined another temporary variable `$t` and then done `($t=$i, $i=...)[0]` but since that's the only place `$t` would be used... I can just use the `$` that's already there.  Maybe this makes more sense: `($i.clone,$i=($i+1)*2)[0]`.

Comment: You could use `$i<>` or `$i.self` or `$i+0` instead of `$=$i`. The important point is that you need to return the **value** in `$i` rather than the **variable** `$i` itself.